# Which layout should i use in order to make a view cover the entire REMAINING screen, when there is a toolbar or bottom navbar?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, layout

I have a bottom navbar and a toolbar in top of the main activity. I want to place a frame layout between these. "match_parent" seems okay for width but when it comes to height, "match_parent" makes the layout cover the entire screen.

A fixed height value saves the day for a specific device with specific screen size but it won't work for any other device with different sizes.

So which layout should i use to make this frame layout to cover only the remaining space left, independently of screen sizes and fixed height values?

[image: I tried it with constraint layout but failed..]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="HELLO"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white">
        </TextView>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentPlace"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.497">
</FrameLayout>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
</com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: please show us some of your codes

Comment: Just make your `FrameLayout`'s `android:layout_height="0dp"`